# UnknownHostException in prestodb

Tags: presto

My Hive metastore and HDFS cluster is not directly accessible to my local machine, and i  use SSH port forwarding to access it.using a dynamic SOCKS proxy with SSH listening on local port 1080,but the error is :  query fail: UnknownHostException linux-hostname

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem myself.Previously，i use the Ethernet ip by adding the network configuration in system settings ,finally,i set the ip static over the file /etc/network/interface and then the program runs successfully.